# How to upgrade from .net 4.0 to .net 4.5 on VPS hosting?

Tags: .net-4.0

I purchased a Windows VPS Hosting with Hyper-V and Windows 2008 R2 x64 Standard Edition, and I have installed WebsitePanel, asp.net 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 on it.
It worked well. Now I hope my VPS hosting support .net 4.5, how to upgrade? what files do I need install on the hosting? Thanks!

And more, will my asp.net 4.0 website be faster if I upgrade the website to asp.net 4.5 and upgrade VPS hosting to .net 4.5?

Comment: [This site is for systems administration or desktop support in a **professional capacity**](http://serverfault.com/faq).  Professionals do not have trouble figuring out how to install a `.net` framework.  Downvoted, closevoted.

Answer (score 1):

Updating `asp.net` \ the `.NET` framework is done by downloading the updated version from Microsoft and installing it.  Version 4.0 to 4.5 is an in-place update process, and the required file can be found at the [Microsoft download page for `.NET` framework version 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653).

As to how to get that file onto your `VPS` and execute it, that's up to you.  This is not something a professional sysadmin would struggle with, or be particularly interested in walking anyone through, generally.

Comment: Additionally, if it is an asp.net website your source files may not be compatible with 4.5 and it could crash your site.  You should always make sure to test out this in a lab environment prior to moving it into production.

Comment: @Dresca  Yeah, that's a very good point.  A professional admin would do that as a matter of habit, but I clearly should have mentioned that explicitly in this case.  Thanks for pointing it out.